# Custom Alertview Button Action not calling

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uialertview

I m Creating a custom alertview With Background image and one button (to dismiss the alert view).But the button action is not calling

[image]

here is my code.

In .h file

```
UIAlertView *alert;
```

In .m file

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];

            [alert setTitle:nil];
            [alert setMessage:nil];
            [alert setDelegate:self];


            UIImage *alertImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stopthegame.png"];
            UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage :alertImage];

            backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 160);

            backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

            [alert addSubview:backgroundImageView];




   UIButton *alertok = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


            alertok.frame = CGRectMake(105, 110, 75,40);

            UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yesorno.png"];
            UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
            [alertok setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instructionok.png"];
            UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
            [alertok setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            [alertok setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [alertok setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];


           [alert addSubview:alertok ]; 

[alertok addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



 [alert show];
```

Here is the code to dismiss the alert

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

}

some one please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also one doubt:apple will accept this custom alert view or not ?

Comment: Why do you need a button to dismiss the UIAlertView if you have the native ones?

Comment: Is the buttonClicked: method actually not being called or is the alert just not being dismissed?

Comment: Note that Apple engineers have explicitly stated many times in WWDC videos and on the developer forums, that you should not be diving into private subview hierarchies like with UIAlertView. You should be writing your own custom alert view class.

Comment: Yes that's true because then you'll have compability problems. So or you write your own AlertView as Mike said or use UIAlertView. If you need to know how to use the UIAlertView tell me and i write you an example.

Comment: Thanks To All for the Reply. Actually The alert is showing as i required(as in picture) but i m unable to dismiss it .is there any idea to dismiss it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this you create in a custom subclass UIView and call it out when needed. https://github.com/FreeApple/CustomAlertView

```
+(void)showCustomPop:(CustomAlertViewType)type inView:(UIView*)view WithTitle:(NSString    
*)title Message:(NSString *)message  actionButtonTitle:(NSString*)actionTitle 
action:(void*)sel cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.But can you please clarify this with some sample codes ?

Comment: I can do better.... Here is an example project I built. I am not releasing this to the public for people to just use in their projects but so they can learn from what I have learned. If you do decide to use this or the code in any of your projects please give proper credit where do. Here is the project https://github.com/FreeApple/CustomAlertView